# neo4j cypher: find all paths with end-nodes that do not have a certain outgoing relationship?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to use cypher to get to the following result:
"Find all paths starting from node A only following relationships on which the property "percentage"<sup>1</sup> is greater 50 and the end of path is a node with property 'type' = 1 and the end of path has no further relationships as specified before (percentage>50 ...)"

(<sup>1</sup>: I'm considering to create a separate relationship-type "MY_RELATIONSHIP_50" for performance reasons)

My Cypher works fine so far:
`start A = node(...)`
`match path = (A)-[rels:MY_RELATIONSHIP*]->(B)`
`where all(rel in rels where rel.percentage! > 50) and B.type = 1`
`return path`

But I can't find a way to express "`the end of path has no further relationships as specified before (percentage>50 ...)`"

I tried to extend the where clause with "`and not B-->C`" but I did neither find out how to qualify with `percentage > 50`.

Is there a way to do this?

Thank's a lot in advance =)

Answer (score 1):

You are kind of looking for the longest path?

So either just sort descending by length and take the top n.

Otherwise something like:

```
start A = node(...)
match path = (A)-[rels:MY_RELATIONSHIP*]->(B)
where all(rel in rels where rel.percentage! > 50) and B.type = 1
AND NONE(r in extract(p in (B-[:MY_RELATIONSHIP]->()) : head(rels(p)) WHERE r.percentage > 50)
return path
```

Comment: @Michael: What is the : (colon) for in the part '... : head(rels..'? I couldn't find any info about using a colon in a list comprehension. Or did you mean | (pipe) ?